# Get the width of a certain column in grid control C#

Tags: c#, wpf, devexpress

Im currently using grid control of devexpress and i tried to get the width of the column in grid control but it sees its returning "NaN" value this is my code for

XAML

```
<dxg:GridColumn FieldName="Order.Order.Comment" Header="Comment" HorizontalHeaderContentAlignment="Left" ReadOnly="True" Name"TestColumn"> 
    <dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
        <dxe:MemoEdit x:Name="PART_Editor" ShowIcon="False" EditMode="Standalone" IsReadOnly="True" IsTextEditable="False" PopupFooterButtons="Close" InvalidValueBehavior="AllowLeaveEditor" PopupMaxWidth="250" MemoTextWrapping="Wrap" MemoVerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ShowBorder="False"/> 
        </DataTemplate> 
    </dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
</dxg:GridColumn>
```

i name the column "TestColumn"

And i have tried to get it on back end

C#

```
var width = TestColumn.width;
```

but the return value is "NaN" did i miss anything on my code? is there a possible way to get the width of a certain column?

Comment: try to specify a value and return it. Cos width property return a Double and if it can't convert the value it gives NaN. This is different to normal VS Grid Column where width could be automatic sizing mode too.

Comment: what do you mean can you give me a sample code? i have tried the ActualWidth property but still "NaN"

Comment: Im saying , set a width first eg: width=50. And see if you still get this error. Default width is Auto. So you can verify that by giving a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know devexpress but I suppose there is a `TextColumn.ActualWidth` property that returns the value you're expecting.

Having a `Width` set to `NaN` is something common in WPF and simply means that the width is not an absolute value, but can vary depending on the layout.

Comment: Hi i have already tried .ActualWidth Property still the return value is "NaN"

Comment: Did you access it after at least one Measure/Arrange pass? I mean after the window has been rendered once and the controls have all been loaded.